# Is it possible to increase map image resolution?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

Here is what my HERE map image looks like:
[satellite image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeB5f.jpg)

As you can see from the image above, the resolution is not very good. Is it possible to get better resolution?

Here is the http request that I used: (note: you will have to enter your own api key for this request to work correctly)

[https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/mapview?apiKey={API_KEY}&ppi=500&sb=km&w=600&h=600&t=3&z=19&c=42.060059,-91.631646](https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/mapview?apiKey=%7BAPI_KEY%7D&ppi=500&sb=km&w=600&h=600&t=3&z=19&c=42.060059,-91.631646)

Answer (score 1):

The ppi attribute in the request will allow the ability to change the resolution but if you're looking to get a clearer satellite picture than that will not be possible.